# Error in the column alignment in the excel sheet while populating data from SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to populate data from a SQL database to excel sheet, using a query in excel sheet. The data is appearing in excel but the columns are aligned in a bizarre way. I just want the columns to get appeared in the same alignment as in the select query.

the select query:

```
select 
VVO.VV_CODE, 
V.Vessel_name, 
VVO.Arrival_date, 
isnull(IGM.VIR_NO,'NULL') as VIR_NO, 
isnull(VVO.TERMINAL_CODE,'NULL') as TERMINAL_CODE,
(SELECT
COUNT(BL_NO)
FROM
BL_DATA
WHERE
VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE AND
ISNULL(UNUSED_FLAG, '') <> '1') as TOTAL_INDEX,
(select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as int) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 19 or Container_Size_Code = 1)  and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as TWENTY_FT,
(select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as int) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 20 or Container_Size_Code = 2) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as FOURTY_FT,
(select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as int) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 3) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as FOURTYFIVE_FT,
(select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as int) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 20 or Container_Size_Code = 19 or Container_Size_Code = 1 or Container_Size_Code = 2 or Container_Size_Code = 3) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) as Total_No_of_Cntrs,
(select((select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as float) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 19 or Container_Size_Code = 1) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE )/2 + (select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as float) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 20 or Container_Size_Code = 2) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ) + (select CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONTAINER_NO) as float) from BL_Container  where (Container_Size_Code = 3) and BL_Container.VV_CODE = VVO.VV_CODE ))) as Total_FFE
from Vessel_voyage VVO, Vessel V, IGM where V.Vessel_code = substring(VVO.VV_CODE,1,3) and VVO.VV_CODE = IGM.VV_CODE
```

The resultant data populated in the excel sheet is as below,

[image: Resultant Excel]

Comment: Before looking at this, let me congratulate you on the effort you put in the screen print to show what the issue is. I hope more people can follow suit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution-

1. Right click EXCEL column header
2. Go to **Table** => **External data properties**

[image]

3. Uncheck "**Preserve column sort/filter/layout**"
4. **Refresh** Excel

The resultant Excel looks as below,

[image]

Comment: Great! I will be deleting my answer since you have found it and entered as an answer.